# Xcode clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (UNITY used for creation)

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

There are many other people with a VERY similar problem to this, but I have not seen Unity itself mentioned in anything related to this issue. My Error is:

Summary of Error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Full Error:

```
ld: could not open bitcode temp file: /Users/Ryan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-
  eovqdsbeqkeftcdnyutjuztsgocg/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity
-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-
iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-
normal/armv7/ProductName.bundle.t3Mkr7/1293.bc for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am using Unity3D for this project and all of the files etc. are made by them, so I do not know really anything about Xcode and how to fix this through Xcode. All help is very appreciated! thank you.

Comment: Try setting bitcode to false in project settings

Comment: Its under "Build Settings" search for "Enable BitCode".Here is a screen shot https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/546001/3652046/eCarfusJozoVUd0/Screen%20Shot%202016-05-08%20at%203.28.27%20AM.png

Comment: You are the best. No joke, that took like 6 hours of attempting to figure out

Comment: too late but: no need to rebuild, in xCode select your target, go to build settings > set Enable Bitcode to NO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting bitcode to false in project settings